# Does the contrary of PDO::FETCH_CLASS exists or mapping an object back in the database

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

With PDO, we can now easily map our fields to an object's property, at a blazing speed. this:

```
class myClass
 {}
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT foo,bar FROM table WHERE id=28');
$stmt->setFecthMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'myClass');
$object = $stmt->fetch();
```

`$object` is now an object of class myClass with foo and bar as properties. neat!

Now, wouldn't it be incredible if I could save my object back in the database just with built-in functions from PDO or php, or even MySQL! something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET * = ?');
$stmt->setUpdateMode(PDO::UPDATE_CLASS);
$stmt->execute($object);
```

As of now, I define custom saving classes for each instance. While fast, this is a hassle for maintaining and very error-prone.

Of course, an object must have exactly the same properties as what it's trying to update, or maybe less fields, but not more.

**does it exists? the lacking part of PDO as the perfect ORM?!**

Comment: No I think not. And PDO is not an ORM!

Comment: of course it's not :p

Comment: But it would not take much effort to Roll You Own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a very prominent feature of oop: destructors!

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

which is very sweet, because what I want is to **maintain the state of my objects between clicks on my website.** This implies different things which I am not sure if they are good practice or not, but it is a bit error prone.

- The fields in the database and the object properties should be the same to simplify destructor code and make it more portable
- I'm using PDO's `FETCH_CLASS` mode to build an object (as in the question)

now the interesting part is with the destructor, which can save back the properties to the relevant fields in the database:

```
function __destruct()
 {
  $whitelist = array_flip(array('foo','bar'));
  // I'm pretty sure not all my properties belong in my table
  foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value)
   {
    if (!isset($whitelist[$key])) continue;
    $fields[] = $key . '=?';
    $values[] = $value; 
    }
  $sql = 'UPDATE table SET ' . implode($fields) . 'WHERE id=?';
  $values[] = $this->getId();
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($values);
  }
```

and there it is! next time I construct my object from the database, it is exactly the same as it was the last time it was accessed.