# Returning database row as an object - is this a good way to do it?

Tags: php, oop

I am building a web application in PHP. Generally, objects will relate to a specific row in the database. I want to write some classes to allow manipulation of those rows. How's this as an example:

Edit: I think this sums up what I'm trying to do, just looking for a practical example in PHP http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

```
// Create a new company record in the database
$data = array(
    'name' => 'My Test Company';
);
try {
    $companyId = Company_Common::create($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
}

// Load the record from the database
try {
    $company = new Company($companyId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
}

// Rename the company
$company->name = 'Company Name New';
$company->save();


class Company_Common {

    function create($data) {
        // add code here to check required fields, insert company record into database, then return row id
    }

}

class Company {

    public function __construct($id) {
        // add code here to load database row from company table based on id
        // throw exception if id not found in database table
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) { // something like this depending on database
            throw new Exception('Company Not Found');
        }
        // dynamically set properties from database row
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
            $this->original->{$key} = $value;
        }

    }

    function save() {
        // load another copy from database
        $original = new Company($this->id);
        // add code here to compare $this with $original, build update query, and update any fields that have changed
    }

    function delete() {
        // add code here to delete company record from database
    }

}
```

Beyond this the above class will include functions like getContactIds, which would retrieve a bunch of row ids from the contacts table, based on the company id.

I'm really just after some feedback on what others think of this approach, and what should or could be done differently/more efficiently. Thanks.

Comment: You can use PDO_FETCH_OBJ

Comment: you should consider stopping using deprecated mysql_* functions, especially since PDO offers so much fun compared to mysql. also is much more oop

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to create an explicit function call to pull data from the database rather than putting it in the constructor. This allows me to create dummy instances of the class for testing and mocking purposes. A general class might look like this:

```
class Car {
     // optionally prevent cars from being instantiated any other way
     private function __construct() {}

    // get car from db
    public static function find($id) {
        // your db stuff here
        $data = $db->where('id', $id)->get();
        return self::make($data);     
    }

    // mock car - create instance and return with data
    public static function make(array $data) {
         $instance = new self();
         return $instance->fill($data);
    }

    // set the provided data to the model
    private function fill(array $data) {
         $this->make = isset($data['make']) ? $data['make'] : false;
         $this->model = isset($data['model']) ? $data['model'] : false;
         return $this;
    }

    public function save() {
        // save to db
    }

}
```

and usage would be:

```
// car with data from db
$car = Car::find(1);


// car with data from input    
$make = $_GET['make'];
$model = $_GET['model'];

$car = Car::make(array('make' => $make, 'model' => $model));
$car->save();



// car with no data
$car = Car::make(array());
```

The main benefit here is that you can create mock objects for unit tests and you can create a model with data from sources other than the db

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)!

For this I love using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` as it allows for cool functions. consider this class:

```
class myClass
 {private $foo,$bar;}
```

let's say I have a table with field foo and bar, and I want to instantiate an object of this class with those field. I'll do like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT foo,bar,'magic' as custom FROM table WHERE id=28");
$stmt->setFecthMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'myClass');
$object = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($object);
```

$object is now an instantiated object of myClass, with three properties, two from the database and one i've manually entered in the sql

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24705611/576767) is the way I save those objects back in the database using oop destructor